# Creating custom android keyboard NOT from scratch (modify system keyboard)

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

What I need is to add a custom key to android keyboard. I know I can implement my own keyboard but implementing all the functionalities (dictionary, swipe, microphone button etc) sounds like a lot of work. I see two solutions:

- modify system keyboard (I expect it not to be possible, but it's
  sometimes good to ask :))
- create my own keyboard but somehow deriving it from existing one

Is any of these possible? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an investigation, answers are:

- not possible
- not possible

:)